# Adding a new enemy every x amount of seconds - Android Game Dev

Tags: java, android, game-physics

I have been following along with the tutorials from:
http://www.edu4java.com/en/androidgame/androidgame.html

Where I stand now is that I am able to populate the screen with a variety of sprites and each character will begin at a random position and they will walk in a random direction.

My objective is to add a new sprite every X amount of seconds but I am not entirely sure how to do this.

Currently my GameView is set up like this:

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView {
       private GameLoopThread gameLoopThread;
       private List<Sprite> sprites = new ArrayList<Sprite>();
       private List<tempSprite> temps = new ArrayList<tempSprite>();
       private long lastClick;
       private Bitmap bmpBlood;


   public GameView(Context context) {
         super(context);
         gameLoopThread = new GameLoopThread(this);
         getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {

                @Override
                public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                       boolean retry = true;
                       gameLoopThread.setRunning(false);
                       while (retry) {
                              try {
                                    gameLoopThread.join();
                                    retry = false;
                              } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                       }
                }

                @Override
                public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                       createSprites();
                       gameLoopThread.setRunning(true);
                       gameLoopThread.start();
                }

                @Override
                public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                              int width, int height) {
                }
         });
         bmpBlood = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);
   }

   private void createSprites() {
         sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.image));
         sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.image));
         sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.image));
         sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.image));
         sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.image));
         sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.image));
         sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.image));
         sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.image));
         sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.image));
         sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.image));
         sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.image));
         sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.image));
   }

   private Sprite createSprite(int resouce) {
         Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resouce);
         return new Sprite(this, bmp);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
         canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
         for (int i = temps.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                temps.get(i).onDraw(canvas);
         }
         for (Sprite sprite : sprites) {
                sprite.onDraw(canvas);
         }
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
         if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastClick > 300) {
                lastClick = System.currentTimeMillis();
                float x = event.getX();
                float y = event.getY();
                synchronized (getHolder()) {
                       for (int i = sprites.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                              Sprite sprite = sprites.get(i);
                              if (sprite.isCollision(x, y)) {
                                    sprites.remove(sprite);
                                    temps.add(new tempSprite(temps, this, x, y, bmpBlood));
                                    break;
                              }
                       }
                }
         }
         return true;
   }
```

}
`

As you can see,  my sprites are being created in createSprites() - however, I am unsure how to create a time to increase the number of sprites.

Could someone please help as I am not sure how to add this into the game loop.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Thread for creation of new sprites and in a loop, add Thread.sleep(1000) line between invoke method declaration and adding new sprite to sprites ArrayList. Just like:

```
private void createSprites(int x) {
   new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            for(int i = 0; i < x; i++) {

            sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.image));
            try
                {
                Thread.sleep(1000); //Waits for 1 second
                }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
                {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

where x is the variable of seconds. So this will create X sprites as a second passes, while your game is still working on background.

Comment: I attempted to modify my createSprites() function as you suggested with adding in the variable x for seconds, however, this forced me to change the call to something like createSprites(10). < Does this now mean that a total of 10 should be created? If so the additional sprites are not being created.

Comment: @user2989774 I've added X as argument just because you've said "adding a new sprite every X amount of seconds". I also edited the code. So this means, all you have to do is passing "amount of sprites" argument to the method. But if you want sprites to be created for every second until game ends, or just specific amount of sprites to be created, just tell me and I will edit the code the way you want.

Comment: I have fixed this code thank you. Just now struggling to add in the listeners using shared preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Create another thread, timer task, or handler and have that run periodically.  Make sure you synchronize your collection properly and only call re draw on the GUI thread.